# How to compute the gradient $\nabla_W \left( x^TW^{-T}W^{-1}x \right)$?

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

> Calculate the following gradient
>
> $$\nabla_W \left( x^TW^{-T}W^{-1}x \right)$$
>
> where $W$ is a $\mathbb{R}^{d×d}$ matrix and $x$ is a $\mathbb{R}^d$ vector. The result should be a $\mathbb{R}^{d×d}$ matrix.

I wonder whether there is a clean and compact form of the result. I first tried to write this as

$$2(W^{-1}x)\frac{d(W^{-1}x)}{dW}$$

but the latter one is a tensor (actually it should be $2 \sum_{i=1}^d(W^{-1}x)_i\frac{d(W^{-1}x)_i}{dW}$ but the next step is messy.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please include **in the body of the question** your own thoughts, the effort made so far, and the specific difficulties that got you stuck.

Comment: Use the directional derivative, then try to extract the gradient from an expression containing the trace. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1933207/339790)'s an example.

Comment: Any progress???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $y=W^{-1}x$ and calculate its differential.
$$\eqalign{
x &= Wy \cr
dx &= W\,dy + dW\,y = 0 \quad (x{\rm \,is\,constant})\cr
dy &= -W^{-1}\,dW\,y \cr
}$$
Write the function in terms of $y$ and find its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
 \phi &= y:y \cr
d\phi &= 2y:dy \cr
 &= -2y:(W^{-1}\,dW\,y) \cr
 &= -2(W^{-T}yy^T):dW \cr
 &= -2(W^{-T}W^{-1}xx^TW^{-T}):dW \cr
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial W}
 &= -2W^{-T}W^{-1}xx^TW^{-T} \cr
}$$
where a colon denotes the trace product, i.e.
$\,\,A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB)$

**NB:** The use of differentials avoids the need to calculate *tensors* as intermediate quantities.