# Minimizing trace involving inverse

Tags: optimization, matrix-calculus, nonlinear-optimization, trace

Given symmetric positive semidefinite rank-$r$ matrix $R \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times m}$, where $r < m$, and scalar $p \geq 0$, I have the following optimization problem in matrix $X \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times m}$.

$$\begin{array}{ll} \underset{X \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times m}}{\text{minimize}} & \text{trace} \left( \left(I + \frac{RX^{H}XR}{\sigma^{2}} \right)^{-1} R^{2}\right)\\ \text{subject to} & \text{trace}\left( X^{H} X \right) \leq p\end{array}$$

Can someone help me with this problem, every approach I tried is futile and leading to a dead-end?

Comment: Is $R$ symmetric or hermitian?  $\;\big(R^T=R\;$ versus $\;R^H=R\big)$

Comment: @greg: Very interesting! Would you be able to share details on the minimization aspect?

Comment: Under the assumption that $R$ is hermitian and ${\rm rank}(R)<m$, you could use the "_skinny_" SVD of $R=UDU^H\,$ with unitary $U\in{\mathbb C}^{n\times n}\;$ to obtain something like $\,X=i\sigma D^+U^H\;$

Comment: @Aruralreader It's just a hunch based on what happens when $R$ is hermitian positive definite. And there's also a typo:  $\;U\in{\mathbb C}^{m\times n}\;$

Comment: Thank you @greg, appreciated. Is there a reference you know of and would share that works through the hermitian positive definite case? I'd like to see how it's done.

Comment: @greg , $R$ hermitian and as mentioned is not of full rank , can you please help me understand your solution using ''skinny'' S.V.D seems a lot like it would help me .please post the solution

Comment: @ Rodrigo de Azevedo  Thank You for the edits

Comment: Also rank(R)  = r $<$ m

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1933207/339790) and try to steal ideas from it.