# Derivative of matrix inverse with respect to a vector

Tags: matrices, derivatives, inverse, matrix-calculus, scalar-fields

How can I find the gradient

$$\nabla_{u} \left(x^T \left(A \, \mbox{diag}(u)\, A^T \right)^{-1} x \right)$$

where $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $u \in \mathbb{R}^d$, are vectors and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times d}$ is a matrix?

I referred to [The Matrix Cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ehwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf) but I cannot find a standard formula there for this expression, and also don't know how to apply some kind of matrix chain rule to compute the derivative in multiple steps.  I'd appreciate any pointers.

---

#### What I tried so far

Let $s=x^T M^{-1} x$, where $M=A \, diag(u)\, A^T$. Then
$$\frac{\partial s}{\partial u} = \frac{\partial s}{\partial M^{-1}} \cdot \frac{\partial M^{-1}}{\partial M} \cdot \frac{\partial M}{\partial u}$$

From the matrix cookbook, I get $\frac{\partial s}{\partial M^{-1}} = xx^T$, $\frac{\partial M^{-1}}{\partial M} = -M^{-1}M^{-1}$, but I don't know how to get $\frac{\partial M}{\partial u}$, and how exactly to combine the above expressions - do I simply matrix multiply them?

Comment: Well, x is independent of u, right? And you can use the chain rule on the identity $M M^{-1} = I$ to find an expression for the gradient of the inverse matrix in terms of the gradient of the matrix itself.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1933207/339790)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$
\def\p{\partial}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\diag#1{\operatorname{diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\operatorname{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
$For typing convenience, define the matrix variables
$$\eqalign{
U &= U^T = \Diag{u} 
 \quad&\implies\quad dU = \Diag{du} \\
B &= B^T = \LR{AUA^T}^{-1} 
 \quad&\implies\quad dB = -B\LR{A\;dU\,A^T}B \\
}$$
and the Frobenius product, which is a convenient notation for the trace, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{AB^T} \\
A:A &= \big\|A\big\|^2_F \\
}$$
Write the objective function using this notation. Then calculate the differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
s &= x^TBx \\&= xx^T:B \\
ds &= xx^T:dB \\
 &= -xx^T:B{A\;dU\,A^T}B \\
 &= -{A^TBxx^TBA}:\Diag{du} \\
 &= -\diag{A^TBxx^TBA}:{du} \\
\grad{s}{u} &= -\diag{A^TBxx^TBA} \\\\
}$$

---

The properties of the underlying trace function allow the terms in a Frobenius to be rearranged in many different ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= B:A \\
A:B &= A^T:B^T \\
CA:B &= C:BA^T = A:C^TB \\
}$$
Unlike the Chain Rule, with the differential approach there is no need to calculate higher-order tensors like $\LR{\grad{M}{u},\;\grad{M^{-1}}{M},\;etc}.\;$ Further, the differential $dB$ obeys the same rules of algebra as the matrix $B$, making it easy to manipulate. Higher-order tensors do not.